# Is it possible to display a jsp page in IE standard view but not in compatible view

Tags: css, jsp, internet-explorer

As i have a problem with my jsp  and css which is not supported by IE compatible view but it works fine in IE standard view and all other browsers so i want to design my code which is adaptable to any browser at any mode kindly give a suggestion to overcome this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must test document.documentMode value, that is only present in IE8 or later. If page is displayed in IE8 standard mode, engine will value 8, but if the page is displayed in IE7 compatibility mode (on a IE8 browser), the value will be 7.

This code snippet is extracted from Microsoft MSDN and it's self explanatory, I think.

```
engine = null;
if (window.navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
   // This is an IE browser. What mode is the engine in?
   if (document.documentMode) // IE8 or later
      engine = document.documentMode;
   else // IE 5-7
   {
      engine = 5; // Assume quirks mode unless proven otherwise
      if (document.compatMode)
      {
         if (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat")
            engine = 7; // standards mode
      }
      // There is no test for IE6 standards mode because that mode  
      // was replaced by IE7 standards mode; there is no emulation.
   }
   // the engine variable now contains the document compatibility mode.
}
```

But you need to know previously wich version of IE is displaying the page. So if it's 8 and the value returned is 7, then is displayed in compatibility mode.